# Is it possible to add a Wake-up word in my action?

Tags: node.js, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

It is required to call your action with a Wake-up word and our action will then converse with the user.
I'd like my action to have the same behaviour as a Google Home, meaning that it needs to hear a wake-up word (e.g. something similar to Hey `<action>`) before listening to a command.

Is it possible to implement it easily? If yes, how ?
I know I can add my wake-up word before each of my training phrase but it's really not efficient.

Comment: I don't quite understand the use case. Is this going to be an action for the Google Assistant? A hardware device?

Comment: Yes it would be an action on Google Assistant. It would serves so that the app will not listen to everything (when someone is talking to someone else) and say the fallback result. An example would be to launch the app while driving and still be allowed to talk to your co-driver

Comment: Okay. There's no built-in wake-up word response, and the action will open the microphone each step. You'd need to add that in to Dialogflow in each intent.

Comment: ok, thanks for the info!